# How to fix this error Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, laravel

UsersController:

```
public function notifications(){
    auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->markAsRead();
    return view('users.notifications',[
            'notifications' => auth()->user()->notifications()->paginate(5)
    ]);
}
```

notifications.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)

   <a href="{{ route('discussions.show', $notification->data['discussion']['slug'])}}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm btn float-right">View Discussion</a>

@endforeach
```

The Error is giving from this code

```
$notification->data['discussion']['slug']
```

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View:
>        C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-forum\resources\views\users\notifications.blade.php)

Comment: What does your `$notification` object contain?

Comment: It was working completely fine, but when i ran composer update. and updated my laravel php etc. it stopped working. I guess i have to downgrade my php to 7.3 but dont have a clue how

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of your notifications doesn't have `discussion` or `slug` properties. First of all check your notifications data in your DB. If you don't need this notifications to be visible move this  HTML tag into 'if' condition and check `@if(isset($notification->data['discussion']['slug']))`.

Comment: Yes i know how the database notifications structure in Laravel looks like but data is a JSON field and some of the prorperties in this json could be invalid for any reason.